# TextInputLayout with outline but transparent background

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

If `boxBackgroundColor` is transparent then boxStroke is invisible

```
<style name="OutlinedRoundedBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">4dp</item>
</style>
```

So is it only possible to have transparent TextInputLayout without outline using custom background?

E.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <corners android:radius="5dp" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/colorEditTextOutline" />

        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had posted a design for it then it would have been easier understand. For this solution If I understand you correctly, you need to add these two things

In style add:

```
<style name="InputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_box</item>
</style>
```

Add color resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/red_bright" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/red_bright" android:state_hovered="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/red_bright" />
  </selector>
```

This solution will have something like this if this is what you want
[image: this is the design whig has whiteBG]

Comment: yes, it's what I needed, now I see outline and I have transparent background, and there is no need to set custom background